# Incorrect Salesforce documentation

Tags: discussion

Is there anything we should do from Salesforce.stackexchange or meta.salesforce.stackexchange to report faulty information when we find it in Salesforce documentation?

Things would get fixed a lot faster if more people were made aware and the **send feedback** button on the Salesforce Documentation pages were utilized in mass.  I didn't know if there was any process to get people on StackExchange to particpate to help make documentation better in general, or if StackExchange determines that they only deal with fixing problems with the actual Salesforce org and not documentation in general?

I couldn't really come up with many pros and cons of this but this pro seems pretty significant.  It makes it easier down the line to debug issues if you know the documentation you are using is correct and also makes it easier for new Users to adopt if the documentation is correct.

Pros

1) Documentation for SFDC would get fixed more quickly.

Cons

1) These add additional questions that don't directly assist people in their Salesforce org.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do **not** think SFSE is the place to organise bug reporting on either salesforce or documentation, and definitely not the place to unite people/call them to action. In my opinion this does not differ much from asking people to vote for your favorite idea on the ideaexchange or to come look at your question in the developer boards or success community.

I think the SFSE chatrooms, #salesforce irc channel, twitter or your success community chatter feed are more appropriate for this.

I do think some questions could be acceptable, such as "I'm trying X but it is not responding as described in the documentation - wat am I doing wrong?", but I do not think we should stimulate/encourage these in order to bring possible flaws in the documentation to the community's attention.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the Salesforce Stack Exchange is not the place to report bugs with Salesforce documentation.  It might be the case that someone has an actual problem and they cite erroneous documentation, but that is a different scenario, e.g., "I keep trying to do X, as documented, with no luck".

Take a look at this recently asked question: [Sending Feedback on Documentation Errors](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/31093/154).

> These reports go directly to the doc writer team, and by far is the
>   quickest & easiest way to give feedback and get improvements in the
>   doc, and is at least as effective as getting bugs logged in the
>   internal system. [I have access to the internal bug system, but still
>   report doc issues via this form].

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something for communities. However , i agree that the more people talk and comment on it is good.

What i can think of is have some kind of : salesforce bugs comunity wiki. 
Each post can have a bug reported. And on the main post some links to reporting sf team. Also links to resolved ideas or something similar.